# How to restrict shifting of a pinch zoomed image to the image borders?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I set up a `scrollView` in storyboard with a single `imageView` using auto layout as shown [here](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/).
In addition I enabled pinch zooming for this `imageView` as described in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html).

The `imageView` has 4 constraints of 0 to the sides of the `scollView`, and it has equal width and height to the main view, which has the `scrollView` as subview.

The `imageView` has `aspectFit` scaling mode, so in the unzoomed state, the image will extend fully from left to right, or from top to bottom (or both).
In the following example, it extends from top to bottom, leaving some background visible left and right:
[image]

I can pinch zoom the image so that it is larger than the screen:
[image]

I can shift the zoomed image up or down, but the movement stops before the background becomes visible on top or bottom. This is want I want.

However, I can shift the zoomed image left or right so that the background can be seen:
[image]

How can I avoid shifting the image so far (here, to the right). Like with top or bottom, it should stop moving at the border, so that no background becomes visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ideal solution but I hope it will help:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    [self adjustScrollViewInsets];
}

- (void)adjustScrollViewInsets {
    CGFloat imageWidth = self.imageView.image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = self.imageView.image.size.height;
    CGFloat aspect = imageWidth / imageHeight;
    CGSize imageViewSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
    if (imageViewSize.width / aspect <= imageViewSize.height) {
        [self adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight:(imageViewSize.width / aspect)];
    } else {
        [self adjustHorizontalInsetsWithImageWidth:(imageViewSize.height * aspect)];
    }
}

- (void)adjustHorizontalInsetsWithImageWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    CGFloat horizontalInset = (self.scrollView.contentSize.width - width) / 2;
    if (width < self.scrollView.frame.size.width) {
        horizontalInset = horizontalInset - (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - width) / 2;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -horizontalInset, 0, -horizontalInset)];
}

- (void)adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    CGFloat verticalInset = (self.scrollView.contentSize.height - height) / 2;
    if (height < self.scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        verticalInset = verticalInset - (self.scrollView.frame.size.height - height) / 2;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-verticalInset, 0, -verticalInset, 0)];
}
```

If you have troubles, check out [this repo](https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/VSKSimpleZoomView).

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I tested your code. It computes the inserts correctly. The strange thing is that, after applying setContentInset: with the correct parameters, 1) the display does not change, i.e. the size of the image does not change and the surrounding background (if any) is still visible, 2) it is no longer possible to scroll in the direction where the inserts have been applied (if the original image was landscape, i.e. height < width, after applying setContentInset: (no matter if the zoomed image is vertically smaller or larger): I can no longer scroll in the vertical direction). Any idea?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I found the problem: Your code does not take into account the zoom scaling factor. If, e.g. vertical insets are set, they are set to the visible area, and no vertical scrolling is possible even if the zoomed image would allow it. To correct this, one has to multiply the argument of adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight: with scrollView.zoomScale (horizontally analogously). If you agree, please edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problems with scroll (tested with simulator, 9.1). Did you test a project from my repository or your own implementation? There is no need to account zoom scaling factor because content's size and image view's size are already calculated for current scale. Can you provide more information about you problems with scroll? A video or a sample project would be very helpful.

Comment: I tried it with my own implementation. I will try to provide more info shortly.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works fine. I am trying to find the difference to my code (actually, it is the same except that it requires this zoom factor). Maybe it is related to my view hierarchy, I will check.

Comment: I found the problem in my code: In your code, scrollView has imageView as subview. When scrollView is zoomed, imageView is also zoomed, and no additional scaling factor is required as in your code. In my code, scrollView has an intermediateView as subview, and intermediateView has imageView as subview. When scrollView is zoomed, intermediateView is also zoomed, whereas imageView is NOT zoomed. Thus, adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight:(imageViewSize.width / aspect)*zoomscale, and adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight:(intermediateViewSize.width / aspect) both work. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Yes, everything is fine, except when you are zooming out the image is moving towards the top. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: So calling the adjustScrollViewInsets from scrollViewDidScroll solved that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and implemented in Swift 4.0 as given below and it worked for me.

**Swift 4.0:**

```
    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    adjustScrollViewInsets()
}

func adjustScrollViewInsets() {
    let imageWidth = self.imageView.image?.size.width
    let imageHeight = self.imageView.image?.size.height
    let aspect = imageWidth! / imageHeight!
    let imageViewSize = self.imageView.frame.size
    if imageViewSize.width / aspect <= imageViewSize.height {
        adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight(height: imageViewSize.width / 2)
    } else {
        adjustHorizontalInsetsWithImageWidth(width: imageViewSize.height / 2)
    }
}

func adjustHorizontalInsetsWithImageWidth(width: CGFloat) {
    var horizontalInset = (self.scrollView.contentSize.width - width) / 2
    if width < self.scrollView.contentSize.width {
       horizontalInset = horizontalInset  - (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - width) / 2
    }
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -horizontalInset, 0, -horizontalInset)
}

func adjustVerticalInsetsWithImageHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    var verticalInset = (self.scrollView.contentSize.height - height) / 2
    if height < self.scrollView.frame.size.height {
        verticalInset = verticalInset - (self.scrollView.frame.size.height - height) / 2
    }
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-verticalInset, 0, -verticalInset, 0)
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.